# how to change the size of the image on the button in html/css

Tags: html, css

I've been **trying to change the size of the image on my button**.

Think of it like this: I have a button with an image on it, and it's currently way too big. I've tried scaling it down as such:
`<img src = "Button.jpg" height: "50%"; width: "20%">` and this doesn't work, no matter what I put in as the height and width.

Even changing it to `20px` and `50p`x doesn't do anything. I'd p*refer not having to create a class because* I don't know how to navigate button classes and I'm pretty sure there's a way just to do it like how I'm doing it now.

Also, **it's not actually a button, it's part of a list.** 
`<li><a href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">`
(That's also another issue.)

OK NEW CODE FOR THE BUTTON WITH A CLASS:

```
    <li><a href="https://www.instagram.com/" target="_blank"><button class = "test"></button></a></li>
  </ul>
```

And for my CSS:

```
.test{
background-image: "instaButton.jpg";
height: 100px;
width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: And we can't see your button or image anywhere or the code that you used.

Comment: paste here your button code and image that you are using.. we can't help if you do not share it!

Comment: This should be a helpful answer: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014849/ddg#25014949>.

Comment: i added my code but it was formatted in non-code. not sure how that worked

Comment: @dekzok yup i tried doing that but now my image has disappeared... i will update my code

Comment: hi guys. please take another look at my code and if you know why my image has now disappeared, that would be very helpful. thanks!

Comment: Your question is totally unclear. Your various bits of code have nothing to do with each other. Maybe it's best to delete this question and start over. And then with a complete snippet of HTML, so we can know what to work with. And never put a <button> in an <a>, that's just silly.

Comment: @MrLister why shouldn't I put a button in a? i need it to be part of the list

Comment: @AdrianMarkoe What are you trying to achieve with a <button> in an <a>? If the user clicks it, what is the browser supposed to do? Follow the <a> link? Execute the button's action? Or both? In what order? And are you sure the browser knows that's what you want it do do? Are you sure the _user_ knows? In addition, this has nothing to do with whether the <a> is in a <li> or not.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply custom `height` and `width` to the image, not to the button.

**If you resize the button,** the button size will change, but the image will go out of its boundaries. If you use this option, you can set `overflow:hidden;` to the `button`, but your image will get cropped.

**If you resize the image,** the image WILL be resized, and the button will resize respectively to the image.

Run the following snippet for examples:

```css
button {
    padding: 5px;
    background: #d95753;
    border: 0;
}

.btn-size {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}

.img-size img {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
}
```

```html
<h1>
Initial styling:
</h1>
<button>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</button>

<h1>
If you resize the button:
</h1>
<p>
the button size will change, but the image will go out of its boundaries. If you use this option, you can set overflow:hidden; to the button, but your image will get cropped.
</p>
<button class="btn-size">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</button>

<h1>
If you resize the image:
</h1>
<p>
the image WILL be resized, and the button will resize respectively to the image.
</p>
<button class="img-size">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" />
</button>
```

Comment: now the issue is that the image is smaller than the button, so i can see a gray border. how do i change this?

Comment: hide all button stylings: `button {padding: 0; border: 0; background: transparent;}` You'll see the image only.

Comment: that works. thanks! would you possibly know how to move my button to the far right of my list of buttons? i have it situated like this:

Comment: button1 button2 button3 blah blah.....                                        buttonhere

Comment: so i want it to look like all my buttons on one end, and then the farthest right of the page to have the other button

Comment: You can add `float: right` to the button you want on the far right :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to link to a css file in the header. in the css file you can then say: .class and then you can change the shit. So in the html file, you first should add a class to the button so that the css knows where you're talking about.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this:

```
<img src="Button.jpg" height="50%" width="20%">
```

I think you have a wrong html syntax :)