# How do I reduce the width of the button?

Tags: html, css

[image: EXAPMLE]I have a button that whatever I do it automatically adds padding to the left and right side, which I can't seem to reduce.

I have tried using max-width however this just makes the button move to the left side of the page

```css
.hero-container-2 {
  background-color: #214CCE;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 150px;
}

.hero-container-2 p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.buttom {
  border: solid 2px #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-family: 'PT Mono', monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container-2">
  <span id="contactus"></span>
  <p><span id="contactus">Itching to ask us a question about the club? Want to pick our brains about training, competing or joining? (We usually react quickly, but it might take us a handful of days to reply).</span></p>

  <div class="buttom">
    <span id="contactus">Contact Us</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you have added padding: 15px 40px; means 40px margin in left and right

Comment: Add width button class `width: 120px;` and reduce padding

Comment: Do you mean you want the button to be the full width of the page(blue area)? If that's the case you have set a padding of 150px for the parent container, which affects the button too

Comment: Why are you using a `span`  as a button?  You're not using the right tool for the job.  At the very least I would consider an anchor tag. You've also got your prompt text `Itching to ask....` in a span with the same class as your button (`buttom`??).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set the size of button in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25014849/how-to-set-the-size-of-button-in-html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add these two lines to your css

```
.buttom {
  ...
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

By adding a 'width' to the div, this will try to move to the default left side. Adding 'margin: 0 auto' will center the div

```css
.hero-container-2 {
  background-color: #214CCE;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 150px;
}

.hero-container-2 p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.buttom {
  border: solid 2px #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 40px;
  font-family: 'PT Mono', monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container-2">
  <span id="contactus"></span>
  <p><span id="contactus">Itching to ask us a question about the club? Want to pick our brains about training, competing or joining? (We usually react quickly, but it might take us a handful of days to reply).</span></p>

  <div class="buttom">
    <span id="contactus">Contact Us</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please add snippet Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Add `width` to button class and also add `margin:0 auto;` reduce `padding`. that is,

```
.buttom {
    padding: 15px 30px;
    width:120px;
    margin:0 auto;
}
```

```css
.hero-container-2 {
  background-color: #214CCE;
  display: inline-block;
  margin-top: 150px;
  padding: 150px;
}

.hero-container-2 p {
  display: inline-block;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 2;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.buttom {
  border: solid 2px #ffffff;
  text-align: center;
  color: #ffffff;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px 30px;
  font-family: 'PT Mono', monospace;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  width:120px;
  text-align:center;
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="hero-container-2">
  <span id="contactus"></span>
  <p><span id="contactus">Itching to ask us a question about the club? Want to pick our brains about training, competing or joining? (We usually react quickly, but it might take us a handful of days to reply).</span></p>

  <div class="buttom">
    <span id="contactus">Contact Us</span>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, as I said in my comment, you should be using the right tool for the job; this is to ensure that screen readers and other disability tools know what they're handling.

So, you can get around the spacing issues using margins:

```
<a href="contactus.htm" class="contact-us">Contact Us</a>
```

Styling:

```
a.contact-us {
    width: 25%;
    max-width: 300px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

This is just an example, but, so long as your parent container is set to the correct width, the button will centre itself happily.

Answer (score 0):

```css
     .hero-container-2{
       background-color: #214CCE;
       display: inline-block;
       margin-top: 150px;
       padding: 150px;

       }

      .hero-container-2 p { 
       display: inline-block;
       color:#ffffff;
       text-align: center;
       line-height: 2;
       margin-bottom:50px;

      }

      .buttom {
       border: solid 2px #ffffff;
       text-align: center;
       color:#ffffff;
       cursor: pointer;
       padding: 15px 15px;
       font-family: 'PT Mono', monospace;
       text-transform: uppercase;
       letter-spacing: 1px;
       }
```

```html
<div class="hero-container-2">
    <span id="contactus"></span>
         <p><span id="contactus">Itching to ask us a question about the club? Want to pick our brains about training, competing or joining? (We usually react quickly, but it might take us a handful of days to reply).</span></p>
       
         <div class="buttom">
        <span id="contactus">Contact Us</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding `display: inline-block;` to your `buttom` class should resolve your issue.

Comment: (As a Minion you should have giggled after using the word `buttom`!)